# Firebase: Does orderByKey return an ordered snapshot

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This sounds like a silly question but the docs say:

> orderByKey
>
> orderByKey() returns firebase.database.Query
>
> Generates a new Query object ordered by key.

The query object is ordered by key which means i can do:

```
ref.orderByKey().limitToLast(1)
```

To get the last in order.

But if I do:

```
ref.limitToLast(1).on('child_added', function(s)
{
    ref.orderByKey().limitToLast(2).once('value').then(function(snapshot)
    {
        var val = snapshot[Object.keys(snapshot)[0]];
    });
});
```

Will `val` always be the second last? The docs don't specifically say the snapshot is ordered. Should I just continue to sort it myself to be sure?

Is there a better way to get the second last in order or the last if there is only one every time a child is added? Basically i want the one before the one that was just added.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have this query:

```
ref.orderByKey().limitToLast(2)
```

This query orders the child nodes by key and then returns the last two items.

To access the results in order, use `Snapshot.forEach()`:

```
ref.orderByKey().limitToLast(2).once('value').then(function(snapshot)
{
  snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
    console.log(child.val());
  });
});
```

The first time through the loop will give you the second-to-last item, so if you want to capture that:

```
ref.orderByKey().limitToLast(2).once('value').then(function(snapshot)
{
  var isFirst = true;
  snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
    if (isFirst) {
      console.log(child.val());
      isFirst = false;
    }
  });
});
```